# Swap usage in top's output

Tags: swap

On a Suse linux machine, I have these swap stats from the `top` utility:

```
Swap:  2096472k total,  1230612k used,   865860k free,  1792880k cached
```

What does the last number (1792880k cached) mean, and why is it sometimes higher than the total swap space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the amount of physical memory being used for cache memory. Even though top lists it at the end of swap, it's really got nothing to do swap space.

[Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/en-US/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html) has a nice explanation of all the different types of memory usage.